# Why Spark Dataset.select replacing the column values

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

```
Dataset<Row> ds = .....
ds = ds.select("cola", "colb");
ds.show();
```

DS is loaded properly. DS contains multiple columns . I want to select "cola" and "colb" colums. Those columns do exist , otherwise above code throws error `Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve colA given input columns`. My issue is it replaces the values with column name. How can I retain original values ?

```
expected 

cola | colb
1       2
3       4
```

What I'm getting

```
cola | colb
cola   colb 
cola   colb
```

Comment: Looks like you are selecting literals.  You have to tell spark you're selecting columns.  Try `ds.select($"cola",$"colb")`.

Comment: That looks like problem with upstream JDBC.

Comment: @Andrew I'm using Java and $ gives can't resolve symbol .I did do import org.apache.spark.sql._ . user10938362 you are right. if I do that with a dummy data source it works. Problem is That perticular data source . What is the fix ?

Comment: Try `col("cola")`.  Think that should work,I think.

Comment: import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col; ds = ds.select(col("cola"), col("colb")); same result

Comment: Try to print the dataset directly without select ing any columns. It seems like a up-stream issue

Comment: @RemisHaroon that errors out saying "column_x" is Out of range . I understand (and am sure) it's up-stream issue , but the question is how can I handle this issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you load data into dataSet from DB , Never trust the data is properly loaded until you can see the actual Data.

For this case , I could see the `ds.printSchema` , I could see `ds.count().show()` but when I was doing `ds.select("cola", "colb")` it wasn't showing proper data.

Now a bit of investigation revealed I shouln't use JDBC while loading from memSql

I was using following **Which was wrong** . It can load the schema , count but not the actual data.

```
 Dataset<Row> ds= spark.read()
                .format("jdbc")
                .option("user", getDbUser(true))
                .option("password", getDbPass(true))
                .option("url", h2RawPositions)
                .option("dbtable", h2PositionTableName)
                .load();
```

Instead I used com.memsql.spark.connector ([Source](https://github.com/memsql/memsql-spark-connector) ) , which worked.

```
Dataset<Row> gsProducts = spark.read()
                .format("com.memsql.spark.connector")
                .option("url", memsqlConnection)
                .option("dbtable", mamsqlTableName) 
                .option("query", "select blah, blah frm memSqlTableName")
                .load();
```